# Bind two input elements to a single model attribute

Tags: java, model, getter-setter

I have a simple form with two radios and two dropdowns populated with values from the *same* ENUM class for each radio respectively. At the same time I have to use a model which has only one attribute for the dropdown.

The problem is this model is used by a service, which I cannot change and it expects only this concrete model attribute. I need to decouple and temporarily save the values of the two dropdowns separately in the model. And then based on the selection from the radios, get the temporary value and assign it to the model attribute which then is used by this service.

Do you have a good idea, recommendation how best to achieve something like this?

Currently I have only a getter + setter for this attribute. But if I introduce another two temporary attributes with their gettrers and setters, how do I then assign their values to the 'global' attribute I want to send further?

```
public class TimeoutSetting implements Serializable {   

    public TimeoutEnum timeoutEnum;

    public void setTimeoutEnum(TimeoutEnum timeoutEnum) {
        this.timeoutEnum = timeoutEnum;
    }

    public TimeoutEnum getTimeoutEnum() {
        return timeoutEnum;
    }

}
```

So the `timeoutEnum` needs to be sort of mapped to two additional attributes. Let's say `firstTimeout` and `secondTimeout`, where I store the values from the first and second dropdowns. But then I send to the service only the value in the `timeoutEnum`. I need something similar, such that in the UI the two dropdowns are decoupled from one another, i.e. if I change the value of firstDropdown, the second one stays unchanged and so on (remember they are part of radio buttons, so only *ONE* is active at a time).

---

Comment: Not exactly sure what the issue is...

Comment: I added some extra info. I know it's a bit of a weird scenario.